# I get this TypeError: expected string or buffer while trying to get the response from the server

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2

I am sending a post request with the below data:

```
data = '{"email":"abc@gmail.com","password":"abcdef"}'

response = requests.post(login, data=data,  headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})

dataa = json.loads(response.content)

print dataa

token = dataa['token']

print "Access_token", token

headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":token}

data ='{"form":{"projectLocations":"LOPP","status":"Active","active":true,"name":"AWS","contactName":"xyz",
"contactEmail":"stu@gmail.com","customId":"102","createdCompany":"57972dcad9562e661c73707"}}'

res = requests.post(create_project, data=data,  headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})

dataa = json.loads(res)

print res
```

In return I got the below response:

```
dataa = json.loads(res)

File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads

return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode

obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `print res.text`?

Comment: same error when i print res.text.

Comment: Make sure to put  `print res.text` **above** `dataa = json.loads(res)` otherwise you will see the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

First time you use response content as `loads` argument (`dataa = json.loads(response.content)`) while second time you use response object as `loads` argument (`dataa = json.loads(res)`)
So try to replace

```
dataa = json.loads(res)
```

with

```
dataa = json.loads(res.content)
```